# Solve the system $\frac{dx}{dt}=x-4y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=x+y.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the system $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x-4y$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dt}=x+y.$$

I tried solving it as follows, by first converting the given equation to a vector differential equation
$\frac{dx}{dt}=x-4y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=x+y,$ i.e writing $$\phi=\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix},$$ then, $$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -4\\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix}\phi.$$

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -4\\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ and if $\alpha e^{\lambda t}$ is a solution of this equation, then $\lambda$ is the eigen value of $A$ and $\alpha$ is the eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda.$

The eigen values of $A$ are the roots of the equation $$\begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & -4\\ 1 & 1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=(1-\lambda)^2+4=\lambda ^2-2\lambda +5=0.$$ The roots of this are $1\pm 2i.$

I tried calculating the eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda=1+2i,$ we have $$A\phi=(1+2i)\phi\implies \begin{pmatrix} x -4y\\ x +y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} (1+2i)x\\ (1+2i)y\end{pmatrix}.$$ Equating out the componenets we obtain, $x-4y=x+2ix.$ This means $x=y=0$ and so, we found a trivial solution. Same is the case while using the other eigen value i.e $\lambda =1-2i.$

I don't know where I went wrong, for I expected a non-trivial solution. Is my procedure correct?

Comment: The deduction $x-4y=x+2ix\implies x=y=0$ is valid only if you assume $x,y$ are real. But while the final solution should be real, the general solution can and will be complex. You could alternatively look for *real* trial solutions of the form $e^{-a t}\cos(bt+\phi)$, but this is very tedious algebraically. It's much easier to just take a complex general solution and allow the initial condition to enforce reality.

Comment: @Semiclassical I have posted an answer below. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Hint: Calculate $e^{At}$. Then the solution will be $e^{At}\phi_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1+2i$ you have correctly arrived at the equation $$x-4y=x+2ix$$ or $$-4y=2ix$$

At this stage it is necessary to find **non-zero** values of $x$ and $y$ satisfying this, and there are infinitely many choices, all sets of which are multiples of each other. So you could choose for example $x=2$ and $y=-i$ and this gives you the eigenvector $$\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-i \end{matrix}\right)$$

But any non-zero multiple of this will do just as well.

Similarly for the other eigenvalue.